RSS feed on my github.io pages is not showing the hostname in the URL
I have a website set up on GitHub:  https://waynemroseberry.github.io/.
The RSS feed on the page (which came in by default when I set up Jekyll) presents the pages without the hostname on the website.
RSS feed: https://waynemroseberry.github.io/feed.xml
For example, the 2024/04/05/Think-like-a-tester-and-go-beyond-the-code.html page is presented in the feed as follows:
<entry>
<title type="html">Think Like A Tester And Go Beyond The Code</title>
<link href="/2024/04/05/Think-like-a-tester-and-go-beyond-the-code.html" rel="alternate" type="text/html" title="Think Like A Tester And Go Beyond The Code"/>
<published>2024-04-05T00:00:00+00:00</published>
<updated>2024-04-05T00:00:00+00:00</updated>

I am trying to figure out how to change the URL that the feed presents for my pages, but I cannot find it anywhere.

Your _config.yml file does neither defines the page's url nor the baseurl:
baseurl: "" # the subpath of your site, e.g. /blog
url: "" # the base hostname & protocol for your site, e.g. http://example.com

As far as I can see, you have two options to update your configuration file:

Add the full page URL
url: "https://waynemroseberry.github.io"


Define feed.path in your config file.
feed.path: "https://waynemroseberry.github.io"



You can check this yourself in the code of the minima theme in GitHub. The theme includes the jekyll-feed plugin in it's _config.yml file.
The theme's footer contains the following code:
<a href="{{ site.feed.path | default: 'feed.xml' | absolute_url }}">


{{ site.feed.path }} attempts to fetch the path of the feed file from the site's configuration. If feed.path is defined, it will use this value.

| absolute_url filter appends the base URL of the site to the path, converting it to an absolute URL.


